# How do I keep the top row of an HTML table after it is filtered?

Tags: javascript, html

JS:

```js
<script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#search").on("keyup", function() {
              var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
              $("#datatable tr").filter(function() {
                $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
              });
            });
          });
          </script>
```

The heading part uses `<thead>`. I would like to keep it this way if possible.

When I search something, the heading row goes away - how can I keep it?

HTML:

```html
<thead>
              <td style="font-family: robotobold; color: white"><b></b></td>
              <td style="font-family: robotoblack;text-align:right; font-size:10px; color: #aeafaf;">HEADER1</td>
              <td style="font-family: robotoregular;text-align:left; color: #46e08b;"><b></b></td>
              <td style="font-family: robotoblack;text-align:right; font-size:10px; color: #aeafaf;">HEADER2</td>
              <td style="font-family: robotoregular;text-align:left; color: #F65164"><b></b></td>
            </thead>
              <tr>
                <td style="font-family: robotobold;color: white"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i> <b>col1</b></td>
                <td id="con2"style="font-family: robotobold;text-align:right; color: white;">col2</td>
                <td id="new2"style="font-family: robotoregular;text-align:left; color: #46e08b;"><b>col3</b></td>
                <td id="dec2" style="font-family: robotobold;text-align:right; color: white;">col4</td>
                <td id="decnew2"style="font-family: robotoregular;text-align:left; color: #f65164"><b>col5</b></td>
              </tr>
```

Comment: you don't seem to have used `td` in your JS code

Comment: sorry, @Vandesh, ive updated it.

Comment: Show some html :) or just use a tbody element and edit the contents of it: `$("#datatable tbody tr")`

Comment: @admcfajn done that. Thanks.

Comment: 'the heading row goes away' did you mean the filtering process includes the header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could access the `tr`s only inside the `tbody` like -

```
$("#datatable tbody tr").filter(function() { ...
```

And make sure to wrap the table content in the `tbody` tag in the HTML with the proper structure.

```
<table>
  <thead>...</thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Run the code snippet below to check the above things applied to your example.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#search").on("keyup", function() {
              var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
              $("#datatable tbody tr").filter(function() {
 $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
              });
            });
          });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="search" />
<table id="datatable">  
<thead>
              <td style="font-family: robotobold; color: black"><b></b></td>
              <td style="font-family: robotoblack;text-align:right; font-size:10px; color: #aeafaf;">HEADER1</td>
              <td style="font-family: robotoregular;text-align:left; color: #46e08b;"><b></b></td>
              <td style="font-family: robotoblack;text-align:right; font-size:10px; color: #aeafaf;">HEADER2</td>
              <td style="font-family: robotoregular;text-align:left; color: #F65164"><b></b></td>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="font-family: robotobold;color: black"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i> <b>col1</b></td>
                <td id="con2"style="font-family: robotobold;text-align:right; color: white;">col2</td>
                <td id="new2"style="font-family: robotoregular;text-align:left; color: #46e08b;"><b>col3</b></td>
                <td id="dec2" style="font-family: robotobold;text-align:right; color: white;">col4</td>
                <td id="decnew2"style="font-family: robotoregular;text-align:left; color: #f65164"><b>col5</b></td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
              </table>
```